# Qt generates multiple .so files - which one to use?

Tags: qt, dll, shared-libraries

I am learning about *shared objects (.so)* / *dynamic link libraries (.dll)*. Since I'm on Linux only *.so* files are relevant. Anyway, when I compile a shared library, I get multiple *.so* files - most of which are only links. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Then I created another Qt console application project to test this SO. I had set up all the header files, copied every .so file from previous screenshot to this new project and added

```
LIBS += "libAritmeticnoKodiranjeDLL.so"
```

to project settings. If I compile the project it goes through OK. But when running my test app I get this error:

*./DLLTester: error while loading shared libraries: libAritmeticnoKodiranjeDLL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*

Where is the problem and why do I get so many .so files?

Comment: Why this is done like this is explained here: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Comment: Thank you, interesting reading for insight. However, I can't find a Qt specific way of using them or, even further, what would be wrong with my way - which is reporting the problem that SO cannot be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
LIBS += -lAritmeticnoKodiranjeDLL
```

The specifics of the libraries prefix ("lib") and suffix (".so") will be taken care of by the linker.

Comment: Sadly, I now get *:-1: error: error: AritmeticnoKodiranjeDLL: No such file or directory*.

Comment: Oops, I meant `-lAritmeticnoKodiranjeDLL`. It's been a while since I used qmake. Also you might have to add `-L/path/to/directory/` so that the linker can find the library.

Comment: And you may also have to setup `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` if that directory is not in one of the default library search paths.

Comment: Alright, LIB line in my project settings is now `LIBS += -L/home/me/ProjectFolder/-lAritmeticnoKodiranjeDLL` - also, in terminal I added LD_LIBRARY_PATH and `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` now reports `/home/me/ProjectFolder/:`. I still get error in Qt: *(.text.startup+0x39):-1: error: undefined reference to `AritmeticnoKodiranjeDLL::Author()'*

Comment: That error means that the linker has found the dynamic library and is attempting to link, but not finding a needed symbol in the library. The undefined reference could be that you're missing the implementation of Author() or not exporting the symbol in your link library.

Answer (score 1):

Note how all except one are just symbolic links, and the actual file is the one with most precise version. This is to support different versions of the library, the symbolic links determine which exact version is used when version is not fully defined. If you are installing libs to system library folders, this is kind of important, but if you are just distributing one non-shared version along with your application, then you can use the name without version number.

When running application with custom libraries, you need to add the directory to LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, so runtime linker finds them. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=LD_LIBRARY_PATH . For troubleshooting, you can run `ldd yourprogram` to see what shared libraries are actually loaded, and `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` will let you make sure LD_LIBRARY_PATH is what you think it is.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I edited `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and followed @Kyle's suggestions but I cannot get it to work. Could you help us out (see last comment there)? :)

Comment: Added some troubleshooting tips to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can definitely confirm from my current experience that QtCreator 4.0.3 with Qt 5.7 under Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) when building a shared library (using `TEMPLATE = lib`) then resulting target is `libName.so` (when `CONFIG += unversioned_libname`) or `libNAME.so.1.0.0` (when `CONFIG` unchanged). However an application built with the very same environment links correctly against that library (`LIBS += -Lfolder -lNAME`) during linking but unfortunately during run-time it requests for `linName.so.1` because "Application Output" says `error while loading shared libraries: libNAME.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` (I can see `libName.so.1` in the generated binary of the app but NOWHERE else - not in Make files). I have spent 2 working days to figure this all out. The only way is to manually change the name of generated .so file to fit what application requests.